# Do I need to travel to the UK to renew my Kenyan passport?

Tags: uk, ireland, kenyan-citizens

I'm a dual Kenyan citizen living in Ireland. I lost my Kenyan passport that I got in 2010 last year when moving house. I wanteed to apply for a new one as I'm travelling abroad this December.

I heard though that new e-passports are being dished out any all old ones will be void. Can I get this new one without an old one but just my birth cert?

I also have heard that because biometric data is needed for the passports, Kenyans can only apply in embassies with biometric facilities and I believe thus that I need to travel to London as the Kenyan embassy in Dublin here doesn't have those.

Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange! You might get better answers on expatriates.stackechange.com, our sister site, which has more people who know about issues involving living abroad for longer periods of time.

Comment: http://www.kenyaembassyireland.net/visa-and-consular/kenya-passports/